# how to show outline player csgo

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

i want to figure out how to show / make  a LAN game like pro's in youtube 
i'a a spectator and i want to 
-show the outline (blue/yellow) for players 
-show team members
and how to collect the scores at the end (death match mode)
 i have tried `spec_show_xray` in death match with bots but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

`spec_show_xray 1` does work - just not when you're on the Spectator team to prevent *ghosting*<sup>1</sup>. It only works when watching a game (live via GOTV<sup>2</sup> or replay). So if you're on your own server with bots and just spectating them you'll not be able to use that feature.

---

<sup>1</sup> Ghosting is cheating by having a spectator giving away positions of other players to someone actively playing. This is usually done via voice chats (discord, Teamspeak,...).

<sup>2</sup> GOTV is a game feature allowing spectators to watch a game without actually joining the server. So they can't interrupt the game or interfere/interact with the players. The TV has a delay of a few minutes to prevent ghosting.

Comment: Yes maybe that's why ! Is there a way to creat GOTV on a local server , when i want to host a csgo lan party iam just using one of the laptops and type sv_lan 1 to active the server , this time i really want to make it more professional for streaming stuff , if there an article about it plz let me know thanks

Comment: @MohammedBreky there are plenty of tutorials out there. If you have issues setting one up properly you should ask a new question and give some details where you're stuck.